# Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)

Tags: boot, server, kernel, linux-headers, 23.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu Server 23.10 from 23.04 a week ago. Yesterday, when running the routine dotfile update, I received several kernel upgrade errors to 6.5.0-10. Now it automatically boots to GRUB. Here's the output when running an update.

```
Updating dotfiles...
From https://github.com/denysdovhan/dotfiles
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
All targets have been cleaned
Globs from 'home/.*': ['home/.vimrc', 'home/.zshrc', 'home/.czrc', 'home/.gitignore', 'home/.config', 'home/.gitconfig']
Link exists ~/.vimrc -> /home/caleb/.dotfiles/home/.vimrc
Link exists ~/.zshrc -> /home/caleb/.dotfiles/home/.zshrc
Link exists ~/.czrc -> /home/caleb/.dotfiles/home/.czrc
Link exists ~/.gitignore -> /home/caleb/.dotfiles/home/.gitignore
Link exists ~/.config -> /home/caleb/.dotfiles/home/.config
Link exists ~/.gitconfig -> /home/caleb/.dotfiles/home/.gitconfig
All links have been set up
Path exists /home/caleb/.config
All paths have been set up
Skipping action shell

==> All tasks executed successfully
Updating Zsh plugins...
Loaded ~/.config/sheldon/plugins.toml
   Checked ~/.dotfiles/prompt
   Checked https://github.com/djui/alias-tips
   Checked https://github.com/hlissner/zsh-autopair
   Checked https://github.com/agkozak/zsh-z
   Checked https://github.com/romkatv/zsh-defer
   Checked https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt
   Checked https://github.com/marzocchi/zsh-notify
   Checked ~/.dotfiles/lib
   Checked https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh
   Checked https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell
   Checked https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-better-npm-completion
   Checked https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
   Checked https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
Locked ~/.local/share/sheldon/plugins.lock
Done!

Updating Ubuntu and installed packages...
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.homebridge.io stable InRelease
Hit:3 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:5 https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable InRelease
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Hit:8 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic (6.5.0-10.10) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic (6.5.0-10.10) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KDIR=/lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for sgx: 1.41 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/sgx/1.41/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64 failed for sgx(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.5.0.10.12); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
          Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic (6.5.0-10.10) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KDIR=/lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for sgx: 1.41 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/sgx/1.41/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64 failed for sgx(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic (6.5.0-10.10) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic (6.5.0-10.10) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KDIR=/lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for sgx: 1.41 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/sgx/1.41/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64 failed for sgx(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.5.0.10.12); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
          Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic (6.5.0-10.10) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' KDIR=/lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for sgx: 1.41 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/sgx/1.41/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64 failed for sgx(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.5.0-10-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
```

Any advice would be great appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/sgx/1.41/build/make.log for more information." So what does it report?

Comment: This is what it reports:
`➜ cat /var/lib/dkms/sgx/1.41/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for sgx-1.41 for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Sat Oct 28 01:52:04 PM PDT 2023
Makefile:24: *** Can't install DCAP SGX driver with inkernel SGX support.  Stop.`

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Software-Guard-Extensions/Unable-to-install-sgx-DCAP-driver/td-p/1406544 "Linux kernel versions v5.11 and newer have the SGX driver that supports DCAP built in, so you do not have to (and should not try to) manually install the DCAP driver."

Comment: Would it be safe to remove the files associated with the 6.5.0-10 kernel under /boot? That would be: config-6.5.0-10-generic initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.5.0-10-generic System.map-6.5.0-10-generic vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.5.0-10-generic vmlinuz-6.5.0-10-generic

Comment: Please see my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the terminal command:

```
sudo dkms status
```

One, or perhaps the only entry will be something like:

```
sgx/1.41, 6.5.0-10-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Remove it but substitute the exact version and name you found, if needed:

```
sudo dkms remove sgx/1.41 -–all
```

After the command completes without error, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Post any errors or warnings.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour